# How to set Visual Studio 2012 as default for opening *.json and *.md files?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I tried to do that in Control Penel in "Set Default Programs" but there is no option to check one of these files and no option to add other ones.
[image]
When I right click on those files and click "Open width..." and "Choose default program" I don't have any option to choose Visual Studio. When I choose VisualStudio's .exe file it doesn't work too:
[image]
But it CAN open it because I can do it in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio.

Comment: On my Windows 8.1 I make a .json file on my desktop and right click on it and choose open with and there is Visual Studio Selector. Can you open .json from within Visual Studio ?

Comment: yeah, there is something like that, but why it opens each file in separate window and not in new tab?

Comment: So you can open a .json file from withing Visual Studio ? Maybe now there are options to open it with Visual Studio when you right click on the file. For me all the files open in a separate window, but I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close! Go to "Set Associations" (under *Control Panel* -> *All Control Panel Items* -> *Default Programs* -> *Set Associations*) and choose "Change Program...". Afterwards, you should be able to select from suggested programs as a default or choose browse for one.

[image]
<sup>**Set Associations menu**</sup>